How to show that angular velocity in 3D space is indeed a vector by using Feynman' method?
After reading this chapter of Feynman Lectures oh Physics: https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/I_20.html, inspired by Feynman's method in showing that torque is a vector, I decided to show that angular velocity is a vector using his method.

The above image shows the displacement of a particle in the $xy-$plane when it rotates about the origin $O$ from $P$ to $Q$. The image comes from https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/I_18.html.
From the picture, one can deduce that in a small time interval $\Delta t$, the displacement $PQ$ is:
\begin{equation}
r\Delta\theta = -\Delta x\sin{\theta} + \Delta y \cos{\theta}
\end{equation}
where $x$ and $y$ are respectively the $x-$ and $y-$positions of the particle, $r = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$ is the distance of the particle from the origin and $\theta$ is the angle from the positive $x-$axis to the line $OP$. If there is a '$\Delta$' in front of a quantity, that means a small(infinitesimal) change in that quantity. Divide both sides by $\Delta t$ and rearrange gives:
\begin{equation}
\frac{\Delta\theta}{\Delta t} = -\frac{\Delta x}{\Delta t} \frac{\sin{\theta}}{r} + \frac{\Delta y}{\Delta t} \frac{\cos{\theta}}{r}
\end{equation}
Because $\sin{\theta} = y/r$ and $\cos{\theta} = x/r$ and $r = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$:
\begin{equation}
\frac{\Delta\theta}{\Delta t} = -\frac{\Delta x}{\Delta t} \frac{y}{x^2 + y^2} + \frac{\Delta y}{\Delta t} \frac{x}{x^2 + y^2}
\end{equation}
In the limit as $\Delta t \to 0$, the right-hand side of the above equation gives the angular velocity in the $xy-$plane. Denote this quantity as $\omega_{xy}$ and note that $\lim_{\Delta t \to 0} \frac{\Delta x}{\Delta t} = \frac{dx}{dt} = v_x$, which is the velocity of the particle in $x-$direction, and $\lim_{\Delta t \to 0} \frac{\Delta y}{\Delta t} = \frac{dy}{dt} = v_y$, which is the velocity of the particle in $y-$direction:
\begin{equation}
\omega_{xy} = -v_x \frac{y}{x^2 + y^2} + v_y \frac{x}{x^2 + y^2}
\end{equation}
Similarly, the angular velocity in the $yz-$plane, $\omega_{yz}$, and the angular velocity in the $zx-$plane, $\omega_{zx}$, are:
\begin{equation}
\omega_{yz} = -v_y \frac{z}{y^2 + z^2} + v_z \frac{y}{y^2 + z^2}\\
\omega_{zx} = -v_z \frac{x}{z^2 + x^2} + v_x \frac{z}{z^2 + x^2}
\end{equation}
So far so good. Now, in Feynman's example of showing torque being a vector, he introduced a new set of axes, which is generated by rotate the old axes about the $z-$axis by an angle $\phi$ (In Feynman's original example, he used the letter $\theta$ instead of $\phi$. It doesn't matter which letter I use. Here I use $\phi$ to avoid confusion between symbols.) Thus the new set of axes $x'$, $y'$ and $z'$, which tells the position of the same particle in the new axes, can be expressed in terms of the old axes as:
\begin{equation}
x' = x \cos{\phi} + y \sin{\phi}\\
y' = y \cos{\phi} - x \sin{\phi}\\
z' = z
\end{equation}
The similar relation holds for $v_{x}'$, $v_{y}'$ and $v_{z}'$ in the new set of axes too because velocity is a vector. Therefore:
\begin{equation}
v_{x}' = v_{x} \cos{\phi} + v_{y} \sin{\phi}\\
v_{y}' = v_{y} \cos{\phi} - v_{x} \sin{\phi}\\
v_{z}' = v_{z}
\end{equation}
According to Feynman, if I can prove that the new angular velocities in $x'y'-$, $y'z'-$ and $z'x'-$planes have exactly the same relationship with the old angular velocities as that of $x$, $y$ and $z$ with $x'$, $y'$ and $z'$ or of $v_{x}$, $v_{y}$ and $v_{z}$ with $v_{x}'$, $v_{y}'$ and $v_{z}'$, then problem solved-The angular velocity is indeed a vector! Now let's try it!
First consider new angular velocity in the $x'y'-$plane, $\omega_{x'y'}$:
\begin{equation}
\omega_{x'y'} = -v_{x}' \frac{y'}{x'^2 + y'^2} + v_{y}' \frac{x'}{x'^2 + y'^2}\\
= -(v_{x} \cos{\phi} + v_{y} \sin{\phi}) \frac{y \cos{\phi} - x \sin{\phi}}{(x \cos{\phi} + y \sin{\phi})^2 + (y \cos{\phi} - x \sin{\phi})^2} + (v_{y} \cos{\phi} - v_{x} \sin{\phi}) \frac{x \cos{\phi} + y \sin{\phi}}{(x \cos{\phi} + y \sin{\phi})^2 + (y \cos{\phi} - x \sin{\phi})^2}\\
= \frac{-v_x y \cos^2{\phi} + v_x x \sin{\phi} \cos{\phi} - v_y y \sin{\phi} \cos{\phi} + v_y x \sin^2{\phi} + v_y x \cos^2{\phi} + v_y y \sin{\phi} \cos{\phi} - v_x x \sin{\phi} \cos{\phi} - v_x y \sin^2{\phi}}{x^2 \cos^2{\phi} + y^2 \sin^2{\phi} + 2xy \sin{\phi} \cos{\phi} + y^2 \cos^2{\phi} + x^2 \sin^2{\phi} - 2xy \sin{\phi} \cos{\phi}}\\
=\frac{-v_x y + v_y x}{x^2 + y^2}\\
=\omega_{xy}
\end{equation}
where the identity $\sin^2{\phi} + \cos^2{\phi} = 1$ is used. Now this $\omega_{x'y'} = \omega_{xy}$ corresponds to the relationship between the $z-$components of the new and old angular velocity vectors. Now we try to do it for $\omega_{y'z'}$, which corresponds to the $x-$component and I am expecting $\omega_{y'z'} = \omega_{yz} \cos{\phi} + \omega_{zx} \sin{\phi}$:
\begin{equation}
\omega_{y'z'} = -v_{y}' \frac{z'}{y'^2 + z'^2} + v_{z}' \frac{y'}{y'^2 + z'^2}\\
= -(v_{y} \cos{\phi} - v_{x} \sin{\phi}) \frac{z}{(y \cos{\phi} - x \sin{\phi})^2 + z^2} + v_z \frac{y \cos{\phi} - x \sin{\phi}}{(y \cos{\phi} - x \sin{\phi})^2 + z^2}\\
= \frac{-v_y z \cos{\phi} + v_x z \sin{\phi} + v_z y \cos{\phi} - v_z x \sin{\phi}}{(y \cos{\phi} - x \sin{\phi})^2 + z^2}\\
= \frac{-v_y z + v_z y}{(y \cos{\phi} - x \sin{\phi})^2 + z^2} \cos{\phi} + \frac{-v_z x + v_x z}{(y \cos{\phi} - x \sin{\phi})^2 + z^2} \sin{\phi}
\end{equation}
which is not the form I am expecting because $(y \cos{\phi} - x \sin{\phi})^2 + z^2 = y'^2 + z^2 \neq y^2 + z^2$. Similar unexpected result would occur for $\omega_{z'x'}$ (I am expecting $\omega_{z'x'} = \omega_{zx} \cos{\phi} - \omega_{yz} \sin{\phi}$, but this doesn't happen.). Now, this is my question: what has gone wrong in my argument?

UPDATE 18/Dec/2024: After studying some rigid body dynamics, I realised there maybe (i.e. not definitely) something wrong in my expressions for $\omega_{y'z'}$ and $\omega_{z'x'}$. Each of these should represent the angle covered by the movement of the particle per unit time in those planes (i.e. $y'z'-$ and $z'x'-$planes) respectively. If considering the angular velocity from this perspective, maybe the expressions should be different? (Previously the way I got the expressions for the new angular velocities was to add $'$s to every quantity. But maybe I shouldn't have done this and instead I should have resolved the motion into those new planes and derive the angular velocities respectively?)

Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/768288/123208 & links therein. Also see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudovector

I can't check your error , but here is how you can obtain the angular velocity vector
the angular velocity vector is:
$$ \vec \omega=\frac {\vec R\times \vec V}{\vec R\cdot\vec R}\tag 1 $$
with :
$$\vec R=\left[ \begin {array}{c} x\\y\\0
\end {array} \right] 
\quad,\vec V=\left[ \begin {array}{c} v_{{x}}\\ v_{{y}}
\\ 0\end {array} \right]\quad\Rightarrow \quad
\vec\omega_{xy}= \left[ \begin {array}{c} 0\\0\\ 
{\frac {-yv_{{x}}+xv_{{y}}}{{x}^{2}+{y}^{2}}}\end {array} \right] 
$$
and with
$$ \vec R'=S\,\vec R\quad,\vec V'=S\,\vec V\quad,
S= \left[ \begin {array}{ccc} \cos \left( \phi \right) &\sin \left( \phi
 \right) &0\\ -\sin \left( \phi \right) &\cos
 \left( \phi \right) &0\\ 0&0&1\end {array} \right]$$
you obtain from equation (1)
$$ \vec \omega'=\frac {\left(\vec{S\,R}\right) \times \left(\vec{S\,V}\right)}{\left(\vec{S\,R}\right)^T\,\left(\vec{S R}\right)}= \frac {\vec R\times \vec V}{\vec R\cdot\vec R}=\vec \omega$$
if you have one rotation angle ,the transformation matrix $~\mathbf S~$ has no effect on the results

Angular velocity plane yz
with
$$\vec R=\begin{bmatrix}
  0 \\
  y \\
  z\\
\end{bmatrix}\quad,\vec V=\begin{bmatrix}
  0 \\
  v_y \\
  v_z\\
\end{bmatrix}\quad,
S= \left[ \begin {array}{ccc} 1&0&0\\  0&\cos \left( 
\phi \right) &\sin \left( \phi \right) \\  0&-\sin
 \left( \phi \right) &\cos \left( \phi \right) \end {array} \right] \\
$$
bevor the transformation (Eq 1)
$$ \vec \omega_{yz}= \left[ \begin {array}{c} {\frac {-zv_{{y}}+yv_{{z}}}{{y}^{2}+{z}^{2}}
}\\ 0\\ 0\end {array} \right] $$
after the transformation $~\omega_{y'z'}~$ rotation about the x axis
$$ (S\,\vec R)^T\,(S\,\vec R)=\vec R^T\,S^T\,S\,\vec R=\vec R^T\,\vec R=y^2+z^2\,\surd$$
$$ S\,\vec R=\left[ \begin {array}{c} 0\\ \cos \left( \phi
 \right) y-\sin \left( \phi \right) z\\ \sin \left( 
\phi \right) y+\cos \left( \phi \right) z\end {array} \right] \quad,
S\,\vec V= \left[ \begin {array}{c} 0\\\cos \left( \phi
 \right) v_{{y}}-\sin \left( \phi \right) v_{{z}}\\  
\sin \left( \phi \right) v_{{y}}+\cos \left( \phi \right) v_{{z}}
\end {array} \right] 
$$
$$\left(\vec{S\,R}\right) \times \left(\vec{S\,V}\right)=
 \left[ \begin {array}{ccc} 0&-\sin \left( \phi \right) y-\cos \left( 
\phi \right) z&\cos \left( \phi \right) y-\sin \left( \phi \right) z
\\ \sin \left( \phi \right) y+\cos \left( \phi
 \right) z&0&0\\  -\cos \left( \phi \right) y+\sin
 \left( \phi \right) z&0&0\end {array} \right] \,
\left[ \begin {array}{c} 0\\\cos \left( \phi
 \right) v_{{y}}-\sin \left( \phi \right) v_{{z}}\\  
\sin \left( \phi \right) v_{{y}}+\cos \left( \phi \right) v_{{z}}
\end {array} \right]=-z\,v_y+y\,v_z\,\surd
$$

Definition (1) already tells that $\omega$ is a vector. What else should be proven? If we look for proof that the vector product of two vectors is a vector, it would be enough to prove it in one case (for example, the case of torque), and that's all.

@ GiorgioP-DoomsdayClockIsAt-90 I didn’t wanted to prove that angular velocity is a vector, i wanted to show that the components of the angular velocity bevor and after the transformation are equal

@Eli Your argument in your answer says that the old angular velocity and new angular velocity are equal in the plane which is rotated about the axis. I also obtain the same result above. What I am confused about are the angular velocities in other two planes.

@Bruce M see angular velocity e.g. plane $~yz~$.

@BruceM this equation $~\vec \omega_{{{\it y'z'}}}=\vec\omega_{{{\it yz}}}\cos \left( \phi \right) +
\vec\omega_{{{\it zx}}}\sin \left( \phi \right)
~$ is wrong
